# Incidence risk vs -recalculated incidence risk from incidence rates

Tags: odds-ratio, epidemiology, risk, incidence-rate-ratio

I am learning epidemiology and am puzzled with the following issue.

Assume we have a prospective cohort study with the following results:

- 1000 participants alive at baseline (N)
- 12 years of follow-up
- 200 participants died over the observation period
- 12000 person-years of follow-up.

According to my calculations, the incidence risk is given by

$$ Risk_{1} = 200/1000 = 0.20 $$

And the incidence rate is:

$$ Rate = 200/12000 = 0.01666667$$

So, the incidence rate is 0.017 deaths per person-year (approximately).

We can convert the incidence rate to a risk again as follows:

$$ Risk_{2} = 1 - e^{(-Rate \times t)} $$

where t is time in years.

$$ Risk_{2} = 1 - e^{(-.01666667*12)} = 0.181 $$

Do you know why the two risks are different. Different assumptions?